# How do I set a wildcard for CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in Django?

Tags: python, django, csrf

After updating from Django 2 to Django 4.0.1 I am getting CSRF errors on all POST requests. The logs show:

"WARNING:django.security.csrf:Forbidden (Origin checking failed - https://127.0.0.1 does not match any trusted origins.): /activate/"

I can't figure out how to set a wildcard for CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS? I have a server shipped to customers who host it on their own domain so there is no way for me to no the origin before hand. I have tried the following with no luck:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://*", "http://*"]
```

and

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["*"]
```

Explicitly setting "https://127.0.0.1" in the CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS works but won't work in my customer's production deployment which will get another hostname.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Django app is running using Gunicorn behind NGINX. Because SSL is terminated after NGINX request.is_secure() returns false which results in Origin header not matching the host here:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/3ff7f6cf07a722635d690785c31ac89484134bee/django/middleware/csrf.py#L276

I resolved the issue by adding the following in Django:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

And ensured that NGINX is forwarding the http scheme with the following in my NGINX conf:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Comment: How does this help with CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it had changed in the 4.0 version as you can see here [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins)

> Changed in Django 4.0:
>
> The values in older versions must only include
> the hostname (possibly with a leading dot) and not the scheme or an
> asterisk.
>
> Also, Origin header checking isn’t performed in older versions.

Note: you are not supposed to use `*` in production.

Comment: The django app and frontend run on the same domain. I just don't know what that domain is at build time. I am not sure why you have to specify CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS when the Host and Origin headers are the same.